# Plotting a Gradient Vector Field in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, field, gradient

I want to compute the gradient of a gray-scale image (*smoothed_plane* in the code) and plot it as a vector field in OpenCV, superposed to an existing image.

I tried to apply  a pair of Sobel operators (I also tried Scharr) to compute the two derivatives along x and y as described in OpenCV documentation, but when I try to plot, the vector field seems to be completely wrong. I would like to understand what is my mistake.

I put some code here to be more clear. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
//img is a gray-scale image
Mat abs_grad_x, abs_grad_y, grad;
Mat g_img;
int ddepth = CV_16S;
int scale = 1;
int delta = 0;    

cvtColor(img,g_img,CV_GRAY2BGR);


smoothed_plane = Mat::zeros(image_height,image_width,CV_8UC1);
gradient_field = Mat::zeros(image_height,image_width,CV_32FC2);

// Smooth the dominant plane by convolution with a Gaussian
GaussianBlur(dominant_plane,smoothed_plane,Size(51,51),image_height*image_width*0.5);

/// Morphological opening (remove small objects from the foreground)
erode(smoothed_plane, smoothed_plane, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(40+1,40+1)));
dilate(smoothed_plane, smoothed_plane, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(40, 40)));
/// Morphological closing (fill small holes in the foreground)
dilate(smoothed_plane, smoothed_plane, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(40, 40)));
erode(smoothed_plane, smoothed_plane, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(40, 40)));

imshow("Eroded plane",smoothed_plane);

/// Gradient X
Scharr( smoothed_plane, grad_x, ddepth, 1, 0, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
convertScaleAbs( grad_x, abs_grad_x );

/// Gradient Y
Scharr( smoothed_plane, grad_y, ddepth, 0, 1, scale, delta, BORDER_DEFAULT );
convertScaleAbs( grad_y, abs_grad_y );

for (int i = 0 ; i < image_height ; i ++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < image_width ; j ++){
        gradient_field.at<Point2f>(Point2f(j,i)) = Point2f(abs_grad_x.at<float>(Point2f(j,i)),abs_grad_y.at<float>(Point2f(j,i)));
    }
}

for (int i = 0 ; i < image_height ; i += flowResolution){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < image_width ; j+= flowResolution){
        Point2f p(j,i);
        Point2f p2(gradient_field.at<Point2f>(p)+p);
        arrowedLine(g_img,p,p2,Scalar(0,0,255),1.5,8,0,0.1);
    }
}//*/

imshow("Gradient Vector Field", g_img);
```

EDIT:

This is a pair of frames of my input/output results, as required

[image]

I tried to print out some values, and in some points I got very high or very low values. 
Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved my problem. The main mistake lied in the access method of the partial derivatives matrices, *grad_x* and *grad_y*. As described [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_mat.html), the method *at.<>()* returns a *Scalar* object, so to get access to the pixel intensity value one should use the *.val[]* field. This is how the code has to be changed:

```
Scharr(smoothed_plane,grad_x,ddepth,1,0,scale);
Scharr(smoothed_plane,grad_y,ddepth,0,1,scale);

for (int i = 0 ; i < image_height ; i ++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < image_width ; j ++){
        Scalar xval = grad_x.at<float>(i,j);
        Scalar yval = grad_y.at<float>(i,j);
        gradient_field.at<Point2f>(i,j) = Point2f(xval.val[0],yval.val[0]);
    }
}
```

and this is the expected result:
[image]

Comment: how did you manage to shrink the arrows? I am trying your initial code and I am getting much bigger arrows compared to what you show in the image above.

Comment: Yeah, I scaled down the arrows magnitude just for visualization purposes. Original arrows appeared bigger to me as well. I didn't say it before because it was unnecessary for my question.

Basically, I set the ending point of each arrow as cv::Point2f p2(p + gf_ptr[j]*0.1), where p is the starting point

Comment: OK I see thanks for the feedback. `gf_ptr` is `Point2f* gf_ptr = gradient_field.ptr<Point2f>(i);` right?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, after trying to use your code directly

```
Scharr(smoothed_plane,grad_x,ddepth,1,0,scale);
Scharr(smoothed_plane,grad_y,ddepth,0,1,scale);

for (int i = 0 ; i < image_height ; i ++){
    for (int j = 0 ; j < image_width ; j ++){
        Scalar xval = grad_x.at<uchar>(i,j); // Notice <uchar> not float
        Scalar yval = grad_y.at<uchar>(i,j);
        gradient_field.at<Point2f>(i,j) = Point2f(xval.val[0],yval.val[0]);
    }
}
```

The < float > suggestion gave me high and unusable values.

Comment: Yes, I think it depends on the depth you want for your destination matrix (ddepth) in Scharr operator. In my case, I changed it to CV_32F, so using <float> worked for me. I suppose <uchar> should work for CV_8U (CV_16S too?). Thanks anyway :)