# Wrong gradient vector field OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, gradient

I try to display the gradient vector field of an image in OpenCV (C++).

I used the code from [Plotting a Gradient Vector Field in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907838/plotting-a-gradient-vector-field-in-opencv):

```
cv::Mat img(cv::imread("C:/gradient2.png",1));

cv::Mat smoothedPlane = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows,img.cols,CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat gradientField = cv::Mat::zeros(img.rows,img.cols,CV_32FC2);

cv::Mat GradX, GradY;
//cv::Mat AbsGradX, AbsGradY;

int ddepth = CV_16S;
int scale = 1;
int delta = 0;    
auto size = 40;

GaussianBlur(img,smoothedPlane,cv::Size(51, 51),img.rows*img.cols*0.5);

erode(smoothedPlane, smoothedPlane, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(size+1,size+1)));
dilate(smoothedPlane, smoothedPlane, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(size, size)));

dilate(smoothedPlane, smoothedPlane, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(size, size)));
erode(smoothedPlane, smoothedPlane, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(size, size)));

Scharr( smoothedPlane, GradX, ddepth, 1, 0, scale);
Scharr( smoothedPlane, GradY, ddepth, 0, 1, scale);

//convertScaleAbs( GradX, AbsGradX );
//convertScaleAbs( GradY, AbsGradY );

for (int i = 0 ; i < GradX.rows ; i ++)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < GradX.cols ; j ++)
    {
        cv::Scalar xval = GradX.at<float>(i,j);
        cv::Scalar yval = GradY.at<float>(i,j);
        gradientField.at<cv::Point2f>(i,j) = cv::Point2f(xval.val[0],yval.val[0]);
    }
}

auto resolution = 30;

for (int i = 0 ; i < img.rows ; i += resolution)
{
    for (int j = 0 ; j < img.cols ; j+= resolution)
    {
        cv::Point2f p(j,i);
        cv::Point2f p2(gradientField.at<cv::Point2f>(p)+p);
        cv::arrowedLine(img,p,p2,cv::Scalar(0,0,255),1.5,8,0,0.1);
    }
}

cv::imshow("gradient", img);
cv::waitKey(0);
```

If I copy the gradients value via this access:

```
        cv::Scalar xval = GradX.at<float>(i,j);
        cv::Scalar yval = GradY.at<float>(i,j);
```

The outputted result looks like [result with float access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ2FR.png)

If I copy the gradients value via this access:

```
        cv::Scalar xval = GradX.at<short>(i,j);
        cv::Scalar yval = GradY.at<short>(i,j);
```

The outputted result looks like [result with short access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USRyD.png)

The right result should display arrow line coming from the outer border of the dark disk pointing to the outside of the disk. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, I converted the input image to grayscale with:

```
cv::cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

and kept

```
        cv::Scalar xval = GradX.at<short>(i,j);
        cv::Scalar yval = GradY.at<short>(i,j);
```

Here is the result: [Good gradient vector field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKQth.png)